# Can not view products in admin of magento

Tags: magento, product

I am new to magento and i need little help....
Actually I added simple products in magento and was trying to add some configurable products,The simple products were working fine.
While working on configurable products something happened and I can not see any products in manage products area.
I have checked the database and products exists there.

What should I do to fix this issue.....Kindly help

Comment: Maybe this could help with your issues (and others in the future): http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store

Answer (score 0):

you can see associated product

just click on that

then you can see yoursimple product list ,,if not then click on reset filter

Comment: No this does not works either........reset filter click wont show me any products

Comment: is simple product are visible individualy? or please check status for simple product...

Answer (score 0):

Go to catalog manage products and check if the fields are blank and click search

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The simple products will not show if you do not have the attribute set that links the simples to the configurable.  What is the attribute you are using?  Check in the simples if this is set to be a value.  Then go back to the Configurable, go to the associated products and click on 'Reset'. They should now show.